# Checking SQL Table Value / Using return value as parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, database

I am a little new to using ASP.NET with SQL and I am having trouble with this. The function CheckStatus() basically calls a stored procedure to check a table column value which is only going to be 1 or 0. The data type in the table is a bit so my idea was to convert it into a string and do a check from there. After that, it returns 1 or 0.

The second function ChangeFileStatus() is supposed to change the value to either 1 or 0 depending on what it is.

However, my question is can I use my return value as a parameter in another function? I wanted to make an if condition checking for the return value. Please help.

```
private void ChangeFileStatus()
{
    CheckStatus(); // i wanna call this here but use return value as the paramter


    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("spEcovaFilesChangeJobStats", con); //call your stored procedure within the ""
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // this is saying that the command type is a stored procedure
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }



}

private int CheckStatus()
{
    int status = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("spEcovaGetFilesJobStats", con); //call your stored procedure within the ""
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // this is saying that the command type is a stored procedure
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

               string active = rdr["IsActive"].ToString();

                if (active == "1" )
                {
                    status = 0 ;

                }

                else
                {
                    status = 1;
                }


            }
        }

        con.Close();

        return status;


    }
```

Comment: u mean u want to check like `if checkstatus()=='1'` ??

Comment: Check your logic. in both cases the status = 0. If you just get a return value type bit (so 0 or 1 (or perhaps DBNull)) you can use: bool isActive=reader["IsActive"] as bool? ?? false;

Comment: @Tjasun thanks for catching that I just fixed it

Comment: @akhilkumar yeah that's exactly what I want but I'm a little confused on the ExecuteReader() function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method

```
private void ChangeFileStatus() {}
```

to

```
private void ChangeFileStatus(int Status)
{
//check staus value here
}
```

and you can call the method like

```
int Status=CheckStatus();
ChangeFileStatus(Status);
```

or

```
ChangeFileStatus(CheckStatus());
```

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things that I think you might want to reconsider with your application. You said your table stores a bit, Why not use the C# equivalent of bool? no conversion needed. Also about your call to your stored procedure, are you ever expecting more than 1 value? if not why not do something as follows for check status, This provides the user a clear picture versus a magic number that you have to figure out/remember

```
private bool CheckStatus()
{
    bool wasSuccessful = false;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("spEcovaGetFilesJobStats", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        wasSuccessful = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
    return status;
}
```

And if you wanted this to roll into the change status you would only have to change the signature of ChangeFileStatus like [learningNew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3774666/learningnew) 
mentioned. But if your status can only ever be a bit/boolean do you really need to pass it?